# I want to kill the command process without closing the command prompt/putty

Tags: node.js, ssh, https, ssh2-exec

**I want to kill the process of the 'trai' command without closing the putty/command prompt OR how can I run the same command in background process OR where to pass 'CTRL+C' command in this code so that it will exitthe command **

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');
  conn.exec('trai', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
      console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
      conn.end();
    }).on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: '***.***.***.',
  port: 22,
  username: 'frylock',
  password: 'frylock'
});
```

As I am new to NodeJS please help me if i am wrong .

Comment: do you know the pid of the process if yes you can send kill pid on conn.exec('kill '+pid),function (err,stream)

Comment: @VinayPrabhakaran I don't know pid. I tried finding PId but i couldn't know  how to find PId for this process . can you please help in finding it ?

Comment: try this command ....pgrep -f trai

Comment: search for getChildPid

Comment: @VinayPrabhakaran where to try that command ?

Comment: @user3732793 what is the use of getChildPid i am not using any childprocess..even if i use childprocess i can only close the parent process not child process ?

Comment: @VinayPrabhakaran I want to pass CTRL+C command to stop the xtrai command .

Comment: ctrl + z will display the pid then kill -9 the pid

Comment: or ctrl + z then `kill -9 %1`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to forcefully close the `exec()` stream with `stream.close()`, or if you start your command(s) with a pseudo-tty (passing the `pty: true` option to `exec()`) you should be able to send a ctrl-c with `stream.end('\x03')`.